# Cannot find name when using the constructor but can when casting

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, oidc-client-js

I have imported two types.

```
import { UserManager, WebStorageStateStore } from "oidc-client";
```

From looking at the source, both of these are classes with constructors. I can all the constructor of the first, and can cast with the second, but I cannot call the constructor of the second.

Both of these work.

```
let um = new UserManager({});
let w1 = <WebStorageStateStore> {};
```

TypeScript complains about this one. "Cannot find name 'WebStorageStateStore'".

```
let w2 = new WebStorageStateStore();
```

Why cannot TypeScript find the constructor when it is able to cast to the type?

This is the [source for `oidc-client`](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/tree/dev/src).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TypeScript complains about this one. "Cannot find name 'WebStorageStateStore'".

Just because a variable exists in the *type* declaration space doesn't mean its also in the *variable* declaration space. In your case its only in the *type* space.

## More

Declaration spaces are covered here https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/declarationspaces.html

Comment: Indeed. The type definition file defined `WebStorageStateStore` as an interface. Changing it to a class remedied the problem.